# npm config delete proxy works for me

Tags: npm, networking, proxy, winston, etimedout

Had this ERROR CODE "ETIMEDOUT" while trying to install winston library.

After a run the command *npm config delete proxy* i tried again to install winston and it worked for me, this was on MAcOS and using 9.5.1 v of nmp.